# Some junk values is printing. Why?

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote the following piece of code.

```
public class ArrayLessons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(values);
        }
    }

}
```

But the output puts some junk values like this `"[I@5df9aeda"`.

Why it is not showing `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`?

Im very very new to programming and java. So please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: In a nutshell, what you see is the represenation of the address of the values array in the memory. You need to use indexes and know that array indexes start from 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Array index starts from `0`. Use `int i = 0` in `for-loop`.
2. Use `values[i]` to print the `values`.

If you just want to print: Try this code also:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: And if knowing the position of a specific element is not important, use `for(int value : values)`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot direct print array value without giving any index if you want to print its value you must to go through with loop and its indexing like this please see the following example

```
public class ArrayLessonsDem {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(values[i]);
      }
  }

}
```

Array indexing starting point is 0 so you always start with 0 please check my for look and System.out.println Statement care fully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the i variable together with the array. As in `values[i]` instead of only `values`. Also, array indexing is zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Mr. jhn. Also, if you want to print the results in a single line, you cannot use `System.out.println()`. Just use `System.out.print(values[i])`;